# How to implement nested If statement in Laravel Eloquent?

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am using laravel eloquent to fetch data from mongodb.

The scenario is, there are 3 fields:

field_1, field_2, field_3.

field_1 is mandatory while field_2 and field_3 are optional.

If there is field_3 I need to apply where clause on field_3, if there is field_2, where clause will be applied on field_2 or else where clause will be applied on field_1 by default.

Simply I wanna do following with Laravel Eloquent:

```
if(field_3 is notNull){
     -> where(field_3 = "something");
}
elseif(field_2 is notNull){
     -> where(field_2 = "something");
}
else{
     -> where(field_1 = "something");
}
```

I wish to do this with SQL query.
Can I achieve this with Laravel 5.5 Eloquent Model??

Thanks.

Comment: display your sample code

Comment: Please elaborate on what your actual problem is. As it reads, your question is more of a requirement.

Comment: Please check my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52295181/5013099

Comment: I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Following is an example of applying where clause conditionally. Hope following code helps

```
$customers = Customer::where('field_1', $field_1);

if( isset($field_2) )
{
    $customers = $customers->where('field_2', $field_2)
}

if( isset($field_3) )
{
    $customers = $customers->where('field_3', $field_3)
}

$customers = $customers->get();
```

Comment: If possible I wish to achieve this with SQL (laravel eloquent in my case)

Comment: Yes, but as I am using mongodb... field is not creating if there is no data against that field. I cant't get variable with values to put into if statement. So I need to write sql query with if-else statement so that I can skip other two conditions.